# How to remove blank white space below footer?

Tags: html, css, footer, removing-whitespace

I tried to eliminate the white space according to the answered questions that I found. But not of them is working on my side.

I tried to remove the padding in div's footer, but still the white space still there.

How to fix this?

[image]

CSS:

```
footer #bottom-footer{ background: url(/files/bg-testimonials.jpg) no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52); color: #000; text-align: left; padding: 50px 0 50px 0; font-size: 0.8125em; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: normal; position: relative; left: 0; bottom: 0; height: auto; width: 100%; }
.footer-wrap a{ color: #000; }
.footer-wrap a:hover{ color: #d31716; }
.footer-logo a{ margin-bottom: 6px; display: block; }
.footer-socials{ float: none; line-height: 0; text-align: center; padding: 1em 0 2em;}
.footer-socials a{ border-radius: 100%; border: 3px solid #FFF; color: #FFF; display: inline-block; font-size: 1.25em; line-height: 2.50em; margin-left: 0.1em; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 2.50em; height: 2.50em; }
.footer-socials .social-icons span{ cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; }
.footer-socials .socials i{ -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden; }
.tagcloud a{ font-size: 13px !important; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); padding: 8px 10px; margin: 0 2px 4px 0; display: inline-block;  line-height: 1; }
.sidebar .tagcloud a{ background: #23A38F; color: #FFF; }
.bottom-menu{ float: right; margin: 1em 4em 0 0; }
.bottom-menu ul{ list-style-type: none; font-size: 1.1125em; }
.bottom-menu ul li{ display: inline-block; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.8; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #CCC; box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); padding: 1em; margin: 0 0.10em 0 0; background: #FFF; color: #3e3e3e; }
.footerimg{ width:6em; }
.copyright{ margin: 2em 0 0 4em; }
.copyrighttext{ font-size: 1.08em; font-weight: 600; color: #B3B3B3; margin: 0 0 0 0.50em; }
#imgv ul{ list-style-type: none; letter-spacing: 1px; margin-top: -20px; font-size: 0.75em; }
#imgv ul li{ display: inline; }
.social-footer-mobile{ display: none; }
.footer-vertical-line{ border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;width: 9em; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; }
.left{ left: 32.50em; top: 1.65em; }
.right{ right: 32.50em; top: -1.45em; float: right; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bottom-footer" class="footer-menu">
    <div class="ak-container">
    <div class="footer-wrap clearfix">
        <div class="footer-socials clearfix">
        <div class="footer-vertical-line left"></div>
            <div class="socials">
        <a href="#" class="facebook" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><span class="font-icon-social-facebook"></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="twitter" title="Twitter" target="_blank"><span class="font-icon-social-twitter"></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="youtube" title="Youtube" target="_blank"><span class="font-icon-social-youtube"></span></a>
        <a href="" class="linkedin" title="Linkedin" target="_blank"><span class="font-icon-social-linkedin"></span></a>
        </div>
                <div class="footer-vertical-line right"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-columns-4">
            <ul>
                <li>Products</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="All Products">All products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Standard loan">Standard loan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Promo loans">Promo loans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Promo loans">Insurance for loans</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>About Loans</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="How to apply">How to apply</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Our partner stores">Our partner stores</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Terms &amp; Conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Safety guarantee">Safety guarantee</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>For Customers</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Financial literacy">Financial literacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Payments &amp; Guidelines">Payments &amp; Guidelines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Menu">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>Title</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="About us">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="News">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Contacts">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <nav role="navigation">
        <div class="bottom-menu">
            <ul class="footer-desktop-version">
                <li><span class="footer-icon-cs icon-icon-support"></span>Customer Service: <strong>11111111</strong></li>
            <li><span class="footer-icon-cs icon-icon-collection"></span>Collections <strong>1111111</strong></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="copyright">
        <img src="/files/footer.jpg" class="footerimg"><span class="copyrighttext"> All Rights Reserved ® 2017 
            Company Name</span>
        </div><!-- .copyright -->
    </div><!-- .footer-wrap -->
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you provide your html code ? or create a fiddle

Comment: can you provide your working url?

Comment: with such questions I fill myself Gandalf...

Comment: I think it's a background from the main.

Comment: please see the update post with html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows nothing, perhaps you can't reveal your web address no problem.
You need to check something in your `html` any div or content area have `minus` value like `top:-100px` if you set something like this you need to change like `margin-top:-100px`

Comment: I want to share the url but the website is not accessible in the public internet

Comment: the white space is now removed. thanks to you :) i remove the margin in html class

Answer (score 0):

1. first you have to right click on the footer and click inspect
2. then you will see all the css applied to that particular element, select the parent element
3. check if bottom padding is applied to body or footer element
4. if you dont find bottom padding for footer or body element or other parent class of footer specify bottom padding in negative. (eg -5px)

note: you dont need to modify the css directly for testing purpose you can change and check the effect in debugging tool itself (f12 shortcut for debugging tool)

it should be something like:
(element name)  { padding-bottom:-30px); }

also check for bottom margin if padding does not work.

Comment: use any of jsfiddle, bootply or codepen to give us better understanding of your problem.